# Why is the Well ordering principle used in the proof that if there is a walk, then there is a path?

Tags: graph-theory

Lemma 5.4.2. If there is a walk from a vertex u to a vertex v in a graph, then there is a path from u to v.

Proof. Since there is a walk from u to v, there must, by the Well-ordering Principle, be a minimum length walk from u to v. 
If the minimum length is zero or one, this minimum length walk is itself a path from u to v. Otherwise, there is a minimum length walk
v0,v1......vk.
from u=v0 to v=vk where k>=2. We claim this walk must be a path. To prove the claim, suppose to the contrary that the walk is not a path; that is, some vertex on the walk occurs twice. This means that there are integers i; j such that 0<=i<=j<=k with vi=vj. Then deleting the subsequence
v(i+1).....vj
yields a strictly shorter walk
v0,v1......vi,vj+1,vj+2....vk
from u to v, contradicting the minimality of the given walk.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzYSQ.png)

I can't figure out how the Well ordering Principle comes in. The Well ordering Principle is about "Every nonempty set of nonnegative integers has a smallest element." 
Since a walk is a sequence of vertices and edges, how do they relate set of nonnegative integers to a walk?

Comment: Consider the set of *lengths* of walks between $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks, now I got it.